# Remove all the Html content from a string in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, jira, preprocessor

I would like to remove the all HTML contents from the string.

I have a string

```
str= "I am happy with <body> <h1>This is a Heading</h1>  <p>This is a paragraph.</p> </body> 3333  <body> <h1>This is a Heading</h1>  <p>This is a paragraph.</p> </body> your code"
```

I want the final string 
`str= "I am happy with 3333 your code`"

I have written this code to do above task.

```
def removetags(input_str):
    result = ''
    startflag = 0
    start=True
    count=0
    for ch in input_str:
        if ch == '<':
            if count!=len(input_str)-1:
                if input_str[count+1]!='/':
                    start=True
                    startflag += 1


        elif (ch == '>') and startflag :
            if not start:
                startflag -= 1
            start=False

        elif (not startflag) :
            result += ch

        count += 1

    return result

print(removetags(str))
```

This works fine but if you have a `<` in the text then that will not output correctly. So I want to remove using html parsing. Is there any way to do that? I found this library but I couldn't find the way to do that.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

str = "I am happy with <body> <h1>This is a Heading</h1>  <p>This is a paragraph.</p> </body> 3333 > <body> <h1>This is a Heading</h1>  <p>This is a paragraph.</p> </body> your code"

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    got_html_in_tags = False
    html_free_text = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.got_html_in_tags = True

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.got_html_in_tags = False

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if not self.got_html_in_tags:
            self.html_free_text.append(data)


parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(str)
print("".join(parser.html_free_text))
```

This will print `I am happy with 3333 your code` even with '**>**' or '**<**' in text

Comment: how to get it as a final string? @Nuts

Comment: It's working but I want the final string to a variable a=parser.feed(str) doesn't work? I think it's not returning the string. @Nuts

Comment: @Sathiyakugan parser.feed(str) does not return anything. If you want to get html you should call `parser.html_free_text` - it returns list of lines without tags

Comment: it says AttributeError: 'MyHTMLParser' object has no attribute 'html_free_text' @Nuts

Comment: @Sathiyakugan copy the code example  then... I updated the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177186/discussion-between-sathiyakugan-and-nuts).

Answer (score 1):

Another `re` solution:

```
re.sub(r'(<(?P<tag>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)>.*?</(?P=tag)>)', '', string)
```

Tests:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(<(?P<tag>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)>.*?</(?P=tag)>)', '', string)
'I am happy with  3333   your code'
>>> string = "I am happy with <body> <h1>This is a Heading</h1>  <p>This is a paragraph.</p> </body> 3333 > <body> <h1>This is a Heading</h1>  <p>This is a paragraph.</p> </body> your code"
>>> re.sub(r'(<(?P<tag>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)>.*?</(?P=tag)>)', '', string)
'I am happy with  3333 >  your code'
>>> string = "I am <a happy with <body> </body> lal"
>>> re.sub(r'(<(?P<tag>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)>.*?</(?P=tag)>)', '', string)
'I am <a happy with  lal'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex library for that,

```
import re
str= "I am happy with <body> <h1>This is a Heading</h1>  <p>This is a paragraph.</p> </body> 3333  <body> <h1>This is a Heading</h1>  <p>This is a paragraph.</p> </body> your code"
comp = re.compile(r'<([\w]+)[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>')
data = re.sub(comp, '', str)
print(data)
```

May be this help

Comment: that's giving the string 'I am happy with your code'. That does not include '3333' so that part should not be missed.  I just want a HTML parser way to remove this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this recursively ;)

Base case 1: when the text is an empty string, 
return an empty string

Base case 2: when the first letter of the text is a caret, 
search for the closing tag and return call to function with remaining text after closing tag.

```
def remove_tags(text, tags=[]):
  if text == '':
    return text

  if text[0] == '<':
    closing_caret_pos = text.find('>')
    tag = text[0:closing_caret_pos+1]
    is_open_tag = '/' not in tag
    is_close_tag = not is_open_tag
    is_valid_tag = tag[1:-1].isalpha() or tag[2:-1].isalpha()

    if is_valid_tag and is_open_tag:
      tags.append(tag)
      return remove_tags(text[1:], tags)
    if is_valid_tag and is_close_tag:
      tags.pop()
      return remove_tags(text[len(tag):], tags)

  if len(tags) != 0: # when an open tag exists keeping looking
    return remove_tags(text[1:], tags)

  return text[0] + remove_tags(text[1:], tags)
```

Test runs:

```
text = "I am happy with <body> <h1>This is a Heading</h1>  <p>This is a paragraph.</p> </body> 3333  <body> <h1>This is a Heading</h1>  <p>This is a paragraph.</p> </body> your code"
print(remove_tags(text))
>
I am happy with  3333   your code

text = "x<=1 <div> cookies </div>"
print(remove_tags(text))
>
x<=1 

text = "I am <a happy with <body> </body> lal"
print(remove_tags(text))
>
I am <a happy with  lal
```

Comment: Does not work with string `I am <a happy with <body> </body> lal`

Comment: It shouldn't. Your example isn't valid markup. OP mentions nothing about unstructured markup and I'm guessing to handle examples like this a markup parser may be necessary

Comment: It's valid. I may have math question in my html `x<=1 <div> cookies </div>`